# Can we call pfx file as a key store?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, bouncycastle, keystore, public-key-encryption

I have tried to find the difference between keystore and pfx file. But I coun't find the exact difference between. As per my understanding Keystore is a repository where we can store the bulk of certificates in encrypted format. So that no one can hack those certificates without user authentication.

Pfx file is a bag a which can contain a many objects with optional password protected. pfx may contain publickey or not this is optional. Can anyone please explore much more about this?

Comment: I think you are confusing generic concepts with specific ones. A "pfx" file is obsolete, the standard is now called PKCS12. A pkcs12 file is a file whose contents conform to the [PKCS12 standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7292). A "keystore" is simply a generic concept denoting storage of cryptographic keys. Java, on the other hand, has a specific concept of a KeyStore class. In Java a keystore is an implementation of the KeyStore class. Java has a built-in implementation of a PKCS12 keystore. You just read in the PKCS12 file using the `KeyStore.load()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JamesKPolk